# EmberJS global error when running tests

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

I am trying to integrate automated testing using Ember Testing.

The application runs fine on browser, without any errors.  I tried simply running

```
ember test
```

on command line, but get a bunch of global errors and all the tests fail.

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
not ok 1 PhantomJS 2.1 - Global error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ',' at http://localhost:4302/assets/vendor.js, line 145617

not ok 2 PhantomJS 2.1 - Global error: Error: Could not find module ember-metal/core required by: ember-testing/index at http://localhost:4302/assets/test-support.js, line 62

not ok 3 PhantomJS 2.1 - Global error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define at http://localhost:4302/assets/tests.js, line 1

...
```

When I run the tests on the browser, I do not get the syntax error (first one above), the first error is

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `analogue/resolver` imported from `analogue/tests/helpers/resolver`
```

These don't make sense to me since I shouldn't be editing vendor.js and the modules it says it cannot find are there.  Any ideas?

Comment: What version of ember are you using?

Comment: Do you have all the [prerequisites](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#prerequisites) installed? Mainly phantomjs

Comment: Have you tried running the tests in browser with `-s` flag and see browser console? Sometimes there are error that are easy to understand there

Comment: i'm using the following versions:
ember-cli: 2.4.3
node: 4.4.2
bower: 1.7.9
phantomjs: 2.1.1
git: 1.7.1

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else (like me) ends up here with a similar problem.

In my case the list of errors always started with a random SyntaxError (sometimes about '(' or '!'). The actual referenced line usually never even contained these symbols.

The solution for me was to downgrade phantomjs from 2.1 to a 1.9 version

```
npm install -g phantomjs@1.9.20
```

(use `nvm` or `nave` to make your life easier in these cases)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just needed a fresh PhantomJS installation

```
npm uninstall phantomjs -g
npm install phantomjs -g
```